# Laravel route optional parameter issue

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade, restful-url

My route is:

```
Route::get('members/{name?}/{id}', 'Sample1Controller@sampleFn1');
Route::get('members/{id}/edit', 'Sample2Controller@sampleFn2');
```

When i click the url link from blade,

```
<a href="members/1/edit">Edit</a>
```

it goes to the first route and calls Sample1Controller@sampleFn1. Why?? Please help..

When I click the link..I want to go the second route and calls Sample2Controller@sampleFn2. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you visit `members/1/edit`, since it can match either route you have up there, it chooses the first one, `1` = $name and `edit` = $id. Always put your routes with parameters last, and routes with static text first. You can also do filters or where clauses on your routes, like some of the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('members/{name?}/{id}', 'Sample1Controller@sampleFn1');
```

Both URL's look the same for laravel, in this case, $name is being set to "1" and $id is being set to "edit".
You need to avoid ambiguity by moving the optional parameter to the end
And the status text one level back, in this case:

```
Route::get('members/edit/{id}', 'Sample2Controller@sampleFn2');
Route::get('members/{id}/{name?}', 'Sample1Controller@sampleFn1');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add route where condition to parameters. First I quess is for stings, the second for integers:

```
Route::get('members/{name?}/{id}', 'Sample1Controller@sampleFn1')->where([
    'name' => '[a-z]+',
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
]);
Route::get('members/{id}/edit', 'Sample2Controller@sampleFn2')->where([
    'id' => '[0-9]+'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not validating name or id against any specific constraints so you're /1/edit qualifies... to use the same route definitions you can simply reverse the order of the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
Route::get('members/{id}/edit', 'Sample2Controller@sampleFn2');
Route::get('members/{name?}/{id}', 'Sample1Controller@sampleFn1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      Route::get('/post-delete/{post_id}',[
'uses' => 'PostController@getDeletePost',
'as' => 'post.delete',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

My controller is like this

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id)
{
    $post = Post::where('id',$post_id)->first();
    if(Auth::user() != $post->user)
    {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    $post->delete();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Sucessfully Deleted Taunt']);
}
```

and my blade.php is like this

```
  <a href="{{ route('post.delete',['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a>
```

the above code is for delete u c an try it for edit